# Can I create a fine-tuned model for OpenAI API Codex models?

Tags: json, openai-api, gpt-3, fine-tuning

I'd like to translate user requests into tickets in some sort of structured data format, e.g. JSON. For example:

- User: I want to order two chairs and a desk with three drawers on the left side.
- Output:

```
{
    "type": "furniture",
    "items": [
        { "type": "desk", "qty": 1, "included_items": [{ "type": "drawer", "qty": 3, "position": "left" }] },
        { "type": "chair", "qty": 2 }
    ]
}
```

It looks like GPT-3 itself is not very-well suited for this task, because output is not in the form of natural language, however Codex might be? But I can't find in OpenAI API docs how I can (if it's possible at all?) to create a custom / fine-tuned model for OpenAI API Codex models?

Answer (score 2):

@xara Codex does not support a way to fine tune their model.

What you can do is prompt engineering.

Provide the model some demonstrations and try out whether Codex can perovide you with expected output.

Comment: See https://community.openai.com/t/fine-tuning-for-codex/10689/17 for the feature request to support fine-tuning for Codex

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON is not too involved, you may simply need creative prompt engineering.  In this example, I started by giving ChatGPT your prompt to show a standard input and response and then set it up as a completion task.  This is the exact prompt I used:

````
Please complete the following:
User: I want to order two chairs and a desk with three drawers on the left side.
Output:
```json
{
    "type": "furniture",
    "items": [
        { "type": "desk", "qty": 1, "included_items": [{ "type": "drawer", "qty": 3, "position": "left" }] },
        { "type": "chair", "qty": 2 }
    ]
}
```
User: I want three chairs and a desk with 2 drawers on the left and a desk with 3 drawers on the right.
Output:
```
````

Note that I concluded with three tick marks to indicate that it should immediately begin with the code

ChatGPT returned the following:

```
{
    "type": "furniture",
    "items": [
        { "type": "desk", "qty": 1, "included_items": [{ "type": "drawer", "qty": 2, "position": "left" }] },
        { "type": "desk", "qty": 1, "included_items": [{ "type": "drawer", "qty": 3, "position": "right" }] },
        { "type": "chair", "qty": 3 }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -3):

It is currently in beta, but you can fine-tune the OpenAI codex model on your custom dataset for a charge to improve its performance. Please refer to the following link for details instruction: https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning

Comment: The text-based GPT-3 models can be fine-tuned, Codex cannot (as of Dec 1, 2022).